# Is there a linear algebraic invariant deciding whether a given graph is bipartite? (solved)

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be an undirected graph with $n$ vertices. $G$ may have loops, cycles or multiple edges.

Here is my question: is there an invariant defined only in terms of some matrix associated to $G$, which would tell whether the graph $G$ is bipartite?

I am looking forward to any comments.

EDIT: Theorem 8.2.1 of "Algebraic Graph Theory" by Chris Godsil and Gordon Royle yields an elementary answer:

Let $B$ be the incidence matrix of a simple graph $G$ with $n$ vertices. Assume for simplicity that $G$ is connected. Then $G$ is bipartite if and only if the rank of $B$ is $n-1$.

This statement generalizes directly to graphs of the form above (that is $G$ may have multiple edges or loops).

Comment: The characteristic polynomial, for one.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply and excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Apparently, there is a link between graphs of the form above and a class of certain quivers. Because of this link, I am extremely interested in invariants of the Gram matrix $B^T B$ of the incidence matrix $B$ under unimodular congruence.